# Changing Line Type for specified interval in time series (solid to dotted)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(30)

data <- data.frame(group = factor(1:11), 
                   year = c(rep(2014, times = 11), 
                            rep(2015, times = 11), 
                            rep(2016, times = 11), 
                            rep(2017, times = 11)), 
                   value = runif(44))

data$year <- as.Date(as.character(data$year), 
                     format = "%Y")

ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I would like all lines to the right of when `year == 2015` to be dotted, and all lines to the left of when `year == 2015` to remain solid. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(30)

data <- data.frame(group = factor(1:11), 
                   year = c(rep(2014, times = 11), 
                            rep(2015, times = 11), 
                            rep(2016, times = 11), 
                            rep(2017, times = 11)), 
                   value = runif(44))

data$int_year <- data$year
data$year <- as.Date(as.character(data$year), 
                     format = "%Y")

ggplot(subset(data, int_year <= 2015), aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(data=subset(data, int_year >= 2015), aes(x = year, y = value, color = group), lty=2) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**[EDITED]**

```
data1 <- subset(data, int_year <= 2015)
data2 <- subset(data, int_year >= 2015)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data=data2, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) + 
  geom_line(data=data2, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group), lty=2) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As a side question, if I still want to show the points (the circular dots) in the dotted lines, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: A slightly simpler approach is to just plot everything as dotted, and then rep-plot the solid parts over them: `ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = value, color = group)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line(linetype = 2) +
    geom_line(data = subset(data, year <= '2015-02-06')) + 
    theme_bw()`

Comment: @Clarinetist: edited and updated the code to add the points too.